JAXB: Handle conflicting imported xsds
I have a ton of xsd files which I do not have under control (it's externally managed). My program should handle new xsd files without adapting code.
I would like to generate Model classes for these xsd files using JAXB (using version 2.3.1) which works for some of them. For most of them I cannot generate the Model classes due to duplicate names of complex types. I cannot modify the xsd files since they are managed outside of my project. And I cannot write my own binding.xml file since I don't know the xsd files on compile time (only the CI pipeline does).
Example
That's a snippet of my build.gradle.kts file. In reality I iterate over all xsd files and register an additional task for it since each xsd file get's it's own package name.
val xjc by tasks.registering(JavaExec::class) {
  classpath = jaxb
  mainClass.set("com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCFacade")
  args = listOf(
    "-d", outputDir,
    "-p", packageName
    "-encoding", "UTF-8",
    "-no-header",
    schemaDir
  )
}

Given now there are three xsd files like following. One university.xsd, one student.xsd and one lecturer.xsd. It's a rather simple structure:

one university has multiple lecturers and multiple students
each lecturer and student have addresses
the name of the complex type "address" is the same for student and lecturer

Content of university.xsd:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:lec="http://example.com/lec"
           xmlns:stu="http://example.com/stu" targetNamespace="http://example.com/university"
           xmlns="http://example.com/university" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:import namespace="http://example.com/lec" schemaLocation="lecturer.xsd"/>
  <xs:import namespace="http://example.com/stu" schemaLocation="student.xsd"/>
  <xs:element name="university">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="location" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="lecturers" type="lecturers"/>
        <xs:element name="students" type="students"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="students">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="student" type="stu:student" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="lecturers">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="lecturer" type="lec:lecturer" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>

Content of student.xsd
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://example.com/stu"
           xmlns="http://example.com/stu" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:complexType name="student">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="email" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="address" type="address"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="address">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="streetAndNumber" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="postalCode" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>

Content of lecturer.xsd
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://example.com/lec"
           xmlns="http://example.com/lec" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:complexType name="lecturer">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="email" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="address" type="address"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="address">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="street" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="postalCode" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>

Problem
Since the names of the complex types "address" are the same for student and lecturers, I get following exception:
[ERROR] A class/interface with the same name "org.example.Address" is already in use. Use a class customization to resolve this conflict.
  line 13 of file:/path/to/minimal-reproducer/lecturer.xsd

[ERROR] (Relevant to above error) another "Address" is generated from here.
  line 12 of file:/path/to/minimal-reproducer/student.xsd

[ERROR] Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
  line 13 of file:/path/to/minimal-reproducer/lecturer.xsd

[ERROR] (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.
  line 12 of file:/path/to/minimal-reproducer/student.xsd

Given you cannot modify the xsd files and you do not know the names of the xsd files during development time, do you know how to solve the problem? E.g. is there any possibility to e.g. modify the target package of Students and Lecturers so they are generated to org.example.student.Address and org.example.lecturer.Address? Or is there any possibility to modify the class name so they are generated to org.example.Student_xsd_address and org.example.Lecturer_xsd_address?
